# how do i search for tweets based on location (snscrape)

Tags: python, twitter

what should be added to the search query to search for tweets based on location?

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
keyword = '(COVID OR Corona Vírus)'
maxTweets = 30
tweets = []

for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(keyword + ' since:2020-01-01 lang:pt').get_items()) :
    if i > maxTweets :
        break
    tweets.append([tweet.sourceLabel])

print(tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Twitter` has removed this feature of finding tweets based on location or coordinates.

You could go through this [issue](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/145), and the mentioned ones in that.